Define Phase with Tasks as template or duplicate it
I am currently trying to simplify recurring tasks.
I have a Phase in OpenProject with 15 linked Tasks. I have to perform these tasks every month.
I would now like to create them easily. Unfortunately, I can't find a way to duplicate them or create them as a template. It would be important that it is a combination of Phaseand Tasks.
Is there a way to do this, or do I have to automate it myself via webhooks and Python?
I already searched the official OpenProject pages and the whole system.
